# Powerbi report taking 20 plus seconds to embed in our web app

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We embed powerbi report in our web app using reactjs library and .NET powerbi sdk.

To get all reports we call the GetReportsInGroupAsync method and it is taking more than 8 seconds.

- Get an instance of powerbiclient
- Get workspace details using the same powerbiclient
- Get Reports based on workspace using the same powerbiclient

Next thing what we did here is,

When a user clicks on the link from UI we initiated a new API call to get embedded report details,

1. From the above response we take reportId and called a new endpoint to get embed token and URL details.
2. Get an instance of powerbiclient
3. Get workspace details using the same powerbiclient
4. Get the desired report based on reportId along with workspace
5. Pass this report details to get an embedded token

**For all the above operations report took more than 16 seconds to load.**

**Note:** Even I tried reducing powerbiclient and workspace endpoints from **two to one** call but even though it is taking time to load.

Is there any way to optimize this to less than 8 seconds? If yes please help me.

Comment: What time it takes when you try the same API calls from learn.microsoft.com?

Comment: Tried from the learn.microsoft.com site and it gives less than few seconds. But the issue for me is from API code. Note here is it's straight forward just calling their SDK methods and we tested using swagger and as well from UI.